# ListToArray for submitted form

Tags: coldfusion

I have a web form with multiple elements with the same name for example:

```
<textarea name="instructions"><cfoutput>#struct.instructions# </cfoutput> </textarea>
```

Form is built in html/coldfusion/js and the database to store the data is MS Access.

In the script that I am using to process form submission I am using ListToArray method to get all fields with a given name.

```
<cfset arrayInstr = ListToArray(Form.instructions)>
```

Ok and here is the problem. If the submitted text contains comas ListToArray will interpret it as multiple elements.

For example if I try to submit a string "Bla bla bla bla" everything will be fine, but if string will be "bla, bla, bla" only "bla" will be submitted to database.

Is there other way to process multiple fields with the same name?
I would like to avoid giving unique names.
thank you, 
Janusz

Comment: James gave you a good answer.  I'm wondering why you are so adverse to using unique names.

Comment: That seemed to be easier solution, rather than checking for existence each unique field, I am using for loop to process all of them at once. And in this way I would be able to add more fields to the form without changing script that is processing the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: Is there other way to process multiple fields with the same name?

A: Not directly

Javascript sees the items as a array. What you would need to do is have Javascript loop through all the values and create a string with a different delimiter and put that into a hidden field. The distinction between different `<textarea>`'s and commas would be maintained.

Answer (score 6):

If you give the form field names like instructions1, instructions2, instructions3, it is easy to perform whatever logic you need in a loop.

```
for( var i = 1; i <=3; i++ ){
    var theValue = form["instructions" & i];

    //do whatever you need to do with theValue//
}
```

I think that is much easier to deal with than using JavaScript to add delimters to the form fields.

Comment: Cool. It would be easy using Javascript, but can you dynamically create variables names in similar way in Cold Fusion?

Comment: Yes. Use the same syntax as above, but assign a value on the right side ie `form["instructions" & i] = "something";`. (Edit) BTW, I second the approach above. Much easier than worrying about delimiters ..

Comment: Sometimes the best solution does not necessarily  directly answer the question that is being asked. The only reason I could think of that might make the OP not want unique names is because they might not understand how easy it is to manage these values as unique form fields. I was merely showing how easy it is to do. Answering his question? Maybe not. Solving the underlying problem that lead to his question? Absolutely. IMHO the easiest and best way to solve his problem is to use unique field names.

Comment: For anyone who may be wondering about my rambling comment above. Someone (not going to say who) had posted a comment (which has since been deleted) that my proposed solution did not answer the question since the OP mentioned that he would prefer not to have unique field names.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of the individual form fields by using the [`getHTTPRequestData`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c11.html) function.

```
<cfset Variables.RequestData = getHTTPRequestData()>
<cfset Variables.RequestContent = Variables.RequestData.Content>

<cfset Variables.FormScope = []>
<cfloop index="Variables.CurrentItem" list="#Variables.RequestContent#" delimiters="&">
    <cfset ArrayAppend(Variables.FormScope, URLDecode(ListLast(Variables.CurrentItem, "=")))>
</cfloop>
```